# Is there a way to stop Bluetooth coming back on after an update?

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, software-update

When I do an update via the Settings app on the iPhone (because the computer I sync to iTune doesn't connect to the Net) after the update is done Bluetooth is turned back on. Because updates can be months apart I keep forgetting this, so when it comes back on I forget Bluetooth is turned back on and thus end up having it chew up more power.

Is there a way I can prevent the iPhone from turning on Bluetooth after an update?

Comment: +1 - This is the *most annoying* thing about iOS updates ever. I *always* end up forgetting about it. I have no Bluetooth devices at all and it is a totally pointless "feature" for me.

Answer (score 1):

Apple does this, maybe for information-gathering such as their iBeacon stuff.
There's not much you can do about this behavior and because I've not jailbroken my iPhone I cannot confirm whether jailbreaking your device will prevent this behavior.